# Kotlin make constructor of data class accept both List and MutableList but store a mutable instance of them

Tags: list, kotlin, collections, immutability, constructor-overloading

I want to make a data class which can accept both list and mutable-list and if the list is instance of MutableList then directly make it a property else if it is a List then convert it into a MutableList and then store it.

```kotlin
data class SidebarCategory(val title: String, val groups: MutableList<SidebarGroup>) {
    constructor(title: String, groups: List<SidebarGroup>) :
            this(title, if (groups is MutableList<SidebarGroup>) groups else groups.toMutableList())
}
```

In the above code `Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature` error is thrown by the secondary constructor of the class (2nd line).

How should I approach this? Should I use a so called fake constructor (Companion.invoke()) or is there any better work-around?

Comment: You can use `Collection` instead of `List` in the second constructor

Comment: @IR42 hell yea, but How Collection works in this case? Why List doesn't work? I see almost same signature in them, `Collection<out E>` `List<out E> : Collection<E>`

Comment: Because both `List` and `MutableList` are mapped to the same `java.util.List` class and from JMV it looks like `SidebarCategory` has two identical constructors. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` and `MutableList` are mapped to the same `java.util.List` class ([mapped-types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types)), so from JMV it will look like `SidebarCategory` has two identical constructors.

Instead of `List`, you can use `Collection` in the second constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collection` instead of `List`, and then make an init block that sets it equal to a mutable list, as so:

```
data class SidebarCategory(val title: String, groups: Collection<SidebarGroup>) {
    val groups = mutableListOf<>(groups)
}
```

Comment: Won't work in the case of data classes, groups must be val.